# Accessing a particular element which contains a unique dataset attribute from nested <div>s

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm am relatively new to HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.  I'm building an app that has the diagram of a violin fingerboard.  Got it looking good with HTML/CSS. Things are responsive, clickable, events are working well.  However, I am having difficulty accessing any particular element that has a dataset of "note." I need the element for a particular styling to occur on the note when my app sends a note variable to a function which will sound the note. This is not in response to a click or hover event - I'm playing a pre-programmed melody.

I've tried something like this:
`document.querySelector("[data-note ='G']");`

(hardcoded) to no avail.  Says:

`VM3877:1 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '[dataset.note ='G']' is not a valid selector.` (Got this syntax from an older SO article)

Eventually, I'd like to replace the "G" with an interpolation:

`` document.querySelector(`[data-note ="${note}"]`); ``

but I'm not sure of the proper syntax for this once I figure out how to query select the attribute.  I should add that all the data-note attribute are unique.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="violin">
  <div class="string">
    <div class="open-strings g-string" data-note="G3">G</div>
    <div class="note g-string" data-note="G#3">G#</div>
    <div class="note g-string" data-note="A3">A</div>
    <div class="note g-string" data-note="Bb3">Bb</div>
    <div class="note g-string" data-note="B3">B</div>
    <div class="note g-string" data-note="C4">C</div>
    <div class="note g-string" data-note="C#4">C#</div>
    <div class="note g-string" data-note="D4">D</div>
  </div>
  <div class="string">
    <div class="open-strings d-string" data-note="D4">D</div>
    <div class="note d-string" data-note="Eb4">Eb</div>
    <div class="note d-string" data-note="E4">E</div>
    <div class="note d-string" data-note="F4">F</div>
    <div class="note d-string" data-note="F#4">F#</div>
    <div class="note d-string" data-note="G4">G</div>
    <div class="note d-string" data-note="G#4">G#</div>
    <div class="note d-string" data-note="A4">A</div>
  </div>
  <div class="string">
    <div class="open-strings a-string" data-note="A4">A</div>
    <div class="note a-string" data-note="Bb4">Bb</div>
    <div class="note a-string" data-note="B4">B</div>
    <div class="note a-string" data-note="C5">C</div>
    <div class="note a-string" data-note="C#5">C#</div>
    <div class="note a-string" data-note="D5">D</div>
    <div class="note a-string" data-note="D#5">D#</div>
    <div class="note a-string" data-note="E5">E</div>
  </div>
  <div class="string">
    <div class="open-strings e-string" data-note="E5">E</div>
    <div class="note e-string" data-note="F5">F</div>
    <div class="note e-string" data-note="F#5">F#</div>
    <div class="note e-string" data-note="G5">G</div>
    <div class="note e-string" data-note="G#5">G#</div>
    <div class="note e-string" data-note="A5">A</div>
    <div class="note e-string" data-note="Bb5">Bb</div>
    <div class="note e-string" data-note="B5">B</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've also tried getting one of the parent elements like .violin or the 4 .string nodes collectively with the possibility of iterating and doing a "find", but couldn't find a way to grab the element I wanted.  I've tried using "dataset" but that requires getting a particular class such as ".open-string g-string" or ".note g-string".  I would just like to get straight to the element that has the unique attribute!  Is this possible?

Thanks in advance for any guidance!!

Comment: The first selector is perfectly valid; Working example https://jsfiddle.net/n2xc5ry0/

Comment: NOW it is!!  I'm not sure why I was getting the error that I did, but I opened a fresh console, pasted in my code and got exactly what I wanted - no muss, no fuss. Now I just have to figure out how to work in the interpolation.  If you would like to post your answer, I'll be happy to upvote it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `document.querySelector("[data-note*='G']")`. This will work fine.

```js
document.querySelector("[data-note*='G']").style.color = "orange";
```

```html
  <div class="open-strings g-string" data-note="G3">G</div>
```

> The `[attribute*="value"]` selector is used to select elements whose attribute value contains a specified value.

Comment: Nothing wrong with using the absolute `=` in selector for exact match which seems to be what OP is wanting

Comment: I tried it ..Ran it , it didn't worked :)

Comment: Works fine in jsFiddle link above

Comment: Thanks - I switched the single and double quotes from what I had tried and that solved the problem. Thx so much!!!  Now on to interpolating the variable!

Comment: Hmmm. I see .Yup It should work. But attribute selector * also does fine.

Comment: @mlgvla You are welcome :) Interpolating is done with back-ticks. let me do that ... Give me a moment please :)

Comment: And here is my working interpolation:  ```document.querySelector(`[data-note ="${flashNote}"]`)```

Comment: WIsh you all the very best :) Happy coding